# Sync only favorite songs from iTunes to iPhone

Tags: itunes

I want to synch my iTunes library favorites only to my iPhone 5s. That's about 550 songs. The complete library is too large to synch to my iPhone so I only want to synch favorites. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a playlist with your favourites.
2. Connect your device to your computer and click the device button near the top left of the iTunes window.

[image]

3. Select the type of content you want to sync (for example, Music or Apps) in the sidebar on the left.

[image]

4. Select the Sync checkbox, then select the items you want to sync automatically each time you connect your device.

[image]

5. Chose Selected paylists, artist, albums and genres.
6. Select only the playlist created on point 1 and apply.

[iTunes 12 for Mac: Sync iPod, iPhone, or iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19458?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)